# how do I Build a discord button that replies with a new set of button

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, discord-buttons, discord-interactions

I want it to be where you type in your slashcommand example:"/bank" and it'll show 2 different buttons "offense" "defense" then when you click one of those buttons it'll pop up another set up buttons to click from. Right now it works to where I do /bank and it'll reply with the two buttons offense and defense and it'll reply with you clicked which ever button was clicked. But I want to to reply with another set up buttons.

// this is my button command
bank.js

```
const { SlashCommandBuilder } = require('@discordjs/builders');
const { MessageActionRow, MessageButton, MessageEmbed } = require('discord.js');

module.exports = {
    data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
        .setName('bank')
        .setDescription('Replies with some buttons!'),
    async execute(interaction) {
        const row = new MessageActionRow()
            .addComponents(
                new MessageButton()
                    .setCustomId('offense')
                    .setLabel('Offense')
                    .setStyle('SUCCESS'),

                    new MessageButton()
                    .setCustomId(' defense')
                    .setLabel('Defense')
                    .setStyle('DANGER'),
            );

            const embed = new MessageEmbed()
            .setColor('#0099ff')
            .setTitle('Map: BANK ')
            .setURL('https://discord.js.org')
            .setImage('https://i.imgur.com/s54Riow.jpeg')
            .setDescription('Choose your team shitter');

            await interaction.reply({  ephemeral: true, embeds: [embed], components: [row] });

    },
};
```

this is my
interactionCreate.js

```
module.exports = {
    name: 'interactionCreate',
    async execute(interaction, client) {
        if(interaction.isButton())
        interaction.reply("you clicked" + interaction.customId);
        console.log(interaction);

        if (!interaction.isCommand()) return;
        if (!interaction.isButton()) return;

        const command = client.command.get(interaction.commandName);
        if(!command) return;

        try{
            await command.execute(interaction);
        }catch(error){
            console.error(error);
            await interaction.reply({content : "There was an error while executing action"})
        }

        console.log(`${interaction.user.tag} in #${interaction.channel.name} triggered an interaction.`);
    },
};
```

this is my index.js

```
// Require the necessary discord.js classes
const fs = require('node:fs');
const path = require('node:path');
const { Client, Collection, Intents } = require('discord.js');
const { token } = require('./config.json');

const client = new Client({ intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS] });

client.commands = new Collection();

// command files 
const commandsPath = path.join(__dirname, 'commands');
const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync(commandsPath).filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));

for (const file of commandFiles) {
    const filePath = path.join(commandsPath, file);
    const command = require(filePath);
    client.commands.set(command.data.name, command);
}

// event files
const eventsPath = path.join(__dirname, 'events');
const eventFiles = fs.readdirSync(eventsPath).filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));

for (const file of eventFiles) {
    const filePath = path.join(eventsPath, file);
    const event = require(filePath);
    if (event.once) {
        client.once(event.name, (...args) => event.execute(...args));
    } else {
        client.on(event.name, (...args) => event.execute(...args));
    }
}
// When the client is ready, run this code (only once)
client.once('ready', c => {
    console.log(`Ready! Logged in as ${c.user.tag}`);
});

// When any message is sent in any channel it'll all be logged into the terminal
client.on('message', async msg => {
    if(!msg.content.startsWith(config.prefix)) return;

    var command = msg.content.substring(1);

    if(!client.commands.has(command)) return;

    try{
        await client.commands.get(command).execute(msg);
    } catch(error) {
        console.error(error);
        await msg.reply({content: "there was an error", epthemeral: true})
    }
});

// interaction files
client.on('interactionCreate', async interaction => {
    if (!interaction.isCommand()) return;

    const command = client.commands.get(interaction.commandName);

    if (!command) return;

    try {
        await command.execute(interaction);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        await interaction.reply({ content: 'There was an error while executing this command!', ephemeral: true });
    }
});

// Login to Discord with your client's token
client.login(token);
```

this is my deploy-commands.js

```
const fs = require('node:fs');
const path = require('node:path');
const { REST } = require('@discordjs/rest');
const { Routes } = require('discord-api-types/v9');
const { clientId, guildId, token } = require('./config.json');

const commands = [];
const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync('./commands').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));


for (const file of commandFiles) {
    const command = require(`./commands/${file}`);
    commands.push(command.data.toJSON());
}

const rest = new REST({ version: '9' }).setToken(token);

(async () => {
    try {
        console.log('Started refreshing application (/) commands.');

        await rest.put(
            Routes.applicationGuildCommands(clientId, guildId),
            { body: commands },
        );

        console.log('Successfully reloaded application (/) commands.');
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
    }
})();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We will be working inside of your `interactionCreate.js` where you collect the buttons.

We will need to [update](https://discordjs.guide/interactions/buttons.html#updating-the-button-message) the interaction with the new message. [docs](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/ButtonInteraction?scrollTo=update)

I am noticing duplicate code in your `index.js` and `interactionCreate.js`. This is where you run the slash commands. As a recommendation, you may want to remove the `if (!interaction.isCommand()) return;` in the `interactionCreate.js` and remove the `index.js` listener. Just to have one file handing the `interactionCreate` event. I'll be doing this in the example.

Also you may find a **problem in the future** since in `blank.js` there is a space inside of the interaction `customId`.

### Example with one Listener

```js
const { MessageButton, MessageActionRow } = require('discord.js');

module.exports = {
    name: 'interactionCreate',
    async execute(interaction, client) {
        if (interaction.isCommand()) { // Checks if the interaction is a command and runs the `
        const command = client.command.get(interaction.commandName);
        if(!command) return;

        try{
            await command.execute(interaction);
        }catch(error){
            console.error(error);
            await interaction.reply({content : "There was an error while executing action"})
        }

        console.log(`${interaction.user.tag} in #${interaction.channel.name} triggered an interaction.`);
        return;

    } else if (interaction.isButton()) { // Checks if the interaction is a button
        interaction.reply("you clicked" + interaction.customId);
        console.log(interaction);

        if (interaction.customId === 'offense') { // Check for the customId of the button
            console.log(`${interaction.user.tag} in #${interaction.channel.name} clicked the offense button.`);
        
            const ActionRow = new MessageActionRow().setComponents(new MessageButton() // Create the button inside of an action Row
              .setCustomId('CustomId')
              .setLabel('Label')
              .setStyle('PRIMARY'));
        
            return interaction.update({ // update the interaction with the new action row
              content: 'Hey',
              components: [ActionRow],
              ephemeral: true
            });
        
        }
    }
    },
};
```

### With the original example

```js
module.exports = {
    name: 'interactionCreate',
    async execute(interaction, client) {
        if(interaction.isButton()) {
        interaction.reply("you clicked" + interaction.customId);
        console.log(interaction);


        if (interaction.customId === 'offense') { // Check for the customId of the button
            console.log(`${interaction.user.tag} in #${interaction.channel.name} clicked the offense button.`);
        
            const ActionRow = new MessageActionRow().setComponents(new MessageButton() // Create the button inside of an action Row
              .setCustomId('CustomId')
              .setLabel('Label')
              .setStyle('PRIMARY'));
        
            return interaction.update({ // update the interaction with the new action row
              content: 'Hey',
              components: [ActionRow],
              ephemeral: true
            });
        
        }
        return;
    }

        if (!interaction.isCommand()) return;
        if (!interaction.isButton()) return;

        const command = client.command.get(interaction.commandName);
        if(!command) return;

        try{
            await command.execute(interaction);
        }catch(error){
            console.error(error);
            await interaction.reply({content : "There was an error while executing action"})
        }

        console.log(`${interaction.user.tag} in #${interaction.channel.name} triggered an interaction.`);
    },
};
```

If you need to get the embed that was sent in the original message, you can use [`<interaction>.embeds`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=embeds) to get the embed and then edit it to your liking.

Now **if you don't want to edit the interaction and reply with a new message** remember that if your original message is an ephemeral you **can't delete it**. You can use [replying methods](https://discordjs.guide/interactions/buttons.html#responding-to-buttons).

### Explanation

We are checking for the [`customId`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageButton?scrollTo=customId) that was used when [building the button](https://discordjs.guide/interactions/buttons.html#building-and-sending-buttons). After we create an [action row](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageActionRow) and add the new [message button](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageButton). Then we are [updating](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/ButtonInteraction?scrollTo=update) the original message content with different components.

Feel free to leave a comment if you run into any problems

Comment: Thank you I'm able to understand the process a lot now. But im running into a couple problems now. when i do the code mentioned "Example with one Listener" i get the error "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'command')" but when i do the code mentioned "With the original example" I don't get any errors but the new button doesn't appear when I click the "offense" button from the first button that shows?

Comment: @DCam Gotcha so using the "Example with one Listener." We need to pass `client` to the event file. This will be done inside of the `index.js`. Now I am noticing that you are using one `Collection` for both the message and slash commands. I recommend splitting that just incase to two different collections. Read the comments inside of the file: https://pastebin.com/dheygSAs for `index.js`. For`interactionCreate.js` https://pastebin.com/RdqNJpRR. Please read the comments as it explains the code.

Comment: Adding on to my last comment:
Client is called in the `interactionCreate.js` in the 5th line `async execute(interaction, client) {`. We pass it in the `index.js`. Passing it there will allow us to call client in any event file you want. It would be `(<normal event variables that are passed>, client)`.
Here are some **documentation resources** from my comments:
[Collections](https://discordjs.guide/additional-info/collections.html#collections), [Function Params](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_function_parameters.asp)

Comment: i went back through the code and made the neccesary changes, but i think my "deploy-commands.js" file is preventing the code from working but not sure. ieverything is working fine besides when o do my /bank command in discord it says "the application did not respond."
"index.js" https://pastebin.com/xhQrLiwU
"interaction.js" https://pastebin.com/BJ1kDMYn
"deploy.commands.js" https://pastebin.com/PsnCeNjL
"banks.js" https://pastebin.com/wts8CEfy "bank.js" is in my commands folder

Comment: @DCam yes this is happening because it doesn't look like you are ever setting any commands to the `slash` collection. Which means the `slash` command collection is empty. Are your slash and chat commands both in the same folder? I assumed they were separate and there was code somewhere else adding the commands to the collection. You can just remove the `slash` collection entirely and have **all commands** in the **same collection**. Then just get the commands from there and make sure you don't try to get commands from `slash`.

Comment: so yes i have a commands folder and every command in there is a / command

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245250/discussion-between-crispy-and-dcam).